# PHP - How to programmatically bake out static HTML file?

Tags: php, html

How do you programmatically convert a dynamic PHP file into a static HTML file, that would obviously have all dynamic PHP-related values baked in as static HTML?

Comment: Copy the output, the HTML source of the generated web page! Maybe you mean *how to do this automatically at runtime*?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for caching information, check here: http://www.slideshare.net/anisniit/caching-new

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the beginning of your script place this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
```

At the very end of the script, place this:

```
<?php
    $myStaticHtml = ob_get_clean();
    // Now you have your static page in $myStaticHtml
?>
```

**Output buffering** reference here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere on the top of your PHP file:

```
ob_start();
```

After all the processing:

```
$output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('filename', $output);
```

And if you then also want to output it for that process (for instance if you want to write cache on runtime but also show that page to that user:

```
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

View the HTML source in a browser, and save that.

If you want to do this automatically, then use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

ob_start(); // start output buffering

echo "your html and other PHP"; // write to output buffer

file_put_contents("file.html", ob_get_contents()); // write the contents of the buffer to file

ob_end_clean(); // clear the buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with wget

For example:

```
$ wget -rp -nH --cut-dirs=1 -e robots=off http://www.domain.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open the page and to copy "view source"
You can also use
php function `$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`

and save it in a file

Answer (score 0):

From the related posts:

```
<?php  
  job_start();  // your PHP / HTML code here  
  file_put_contents('where/to/save/generated.html', ob_get_clean());  
?>
```

Comment: The `ob_start();` is needed too.